# Python Print each line of text file into list without \n

Tags: python, list, file, text

I'm still new to learning python and was just wondering how to store each line of a text file into a list without the \n appearing.
I've tried:

```
file = open("test_file.txt", "r")
table = [line.split(') for line in file.readlines()]
```

Outputs:

```
[['Beans', ' 1222', ' 422', ' 6712\n'], ['Eggs', ' 4423', ' 122', ' 2231\n'], ['Tomato', ' 2232', ' 224', ' 2321']]
```

Desired output:

```
[['Beans', '1222', '422', '6712], ['Eggs', '4223', '122', '2231'], ['Tomato', '2232', '224', '2321']]
```

I've tried `temp = file.read().splitlines()` but it ends up storing it all into one list`['Beans, 1222, 422, 6712', 'Eggs, 4423, 122, 2231', 'Tomato, 2232, 224, 2321']`  when I still want each line to be a list itself.
Any help greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, I always use following line to get rid of `\n` every time I read a file:

```py
file = [line.strip("\n") for line in file.readlines()]
```

In your case, just use:

```py
file = open("test_file.txt", "r")
table = [line.strip("\n").split(') for line in file.readlines()]
```

Answer (score 0):

There's two quick solutions.

Since Yihua Zhou already provided one, I'll provide another. Please note that that the strip method might remove more than you want. Look at the docs for `string.strip()` [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_strip.asp).

The `splitlines()` method splits a text on `\n` characters

```py
with open("somefile.txt") as infile:
    table = [line.split() for line in infile.read().splitlines()]
```

Also note that if possible, you should use the `with open()` way to open files, as it closes it automagically. See [this](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/with-statement-in-python) for some explanation...

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your input file is in fact a CSV file where the spaces after commas are to be ignored, in which case you can use `csv.reader` with the `skipinitialspace` option for better readability:

```
import csv

with open("test_file.txt") as file:
    table = list(csv.reader(file, skipinitialspace=True))
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/TechnicalPlumpMathematics